# JQuery Event Listener in AngularJS controller for Dynamic Graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, dynamic, svg

I currently have a web application using AngularJS as an MVC that loads in data from a couple of JSON files and renders a graph in an SVG element with the data

The nodes loaded onto the graph are "circle" elements that each have a unique class name, and I'll just call them nodes.

Each node, when clicked, can either form edges to other nodes in which they're related to, or delete the edges which they're linked to when selected

I'm currently using Jquery event listeners which are assigned to those nodes to handle this job via my graph wrapper which looks like:
`coffeescript
    if node.data.type is "school_node"
      $(circ).click((e) =>
        if e.shiftKey is true then listeners.schoolClicked(node.id)
      )
    else if node.data.type is "department_node"
      $(circ).click((e) =>
        if e.shiftKey is true then listeners.departmentClicked(node.id)
      )
    else if node.data.type is "user_node"
      $(circ).click((e) =>
        if e.shiftKey is true then listeners.userClicked(node.id)
      )`

Is there an Angular way to handle these click events considering these circle elements are constantly being dynamically loaded/deleted? I've tried adding the ng-click attribute via 

`circ = svg("circle").attr('ng-click','clicked()')`

But that doesn't trigger anything when clicked.

UPDATE(1/29/2014) ISSUE RESOLVED:
So I was able to resolve the issue, and although I'm not entirely happy with how it looks, I believe it is as close as I can get to having angular work as an event handler for dynamic svg elements

The directive for my graph looks like this:

```
ICCVApp.directive("graph", ($http,$q) ->
  linker = (scope, element, attrs) ->
  //A lot of file formatting above this line
  options = container: attrs.container
      //Instantiating SVG Element
      scope.g = new CommitteeGraph.initialize(element[0], options)

  //Here is where I assign a single click listener for my SVG element
  if (attrs.graphtype is "explorative")//Checking attribute type for graph
    scope.graphType = "explorative"  //Setting graph type
    scope.committeeBarExists = false 
    do ->
      //Handle Click events within SVG element
      $(element).click((e)->
        //Each node is given the attr "identifier" which is their nodeID in the graph
        nodeClicked = e.target.attributes.identifier
        //If an identifier is found on click, let angular handle the data
        if nodeClicked isnt undefined then scope.nodeClicked(e)
      )
    return //Linker over

  //UI Updates
  scope.nodeClicked = (e) ->
    if e.shiftKey is true //User clicking shift key
      nodeType = e.target.className.baseVal //Node class defines its type
      nodeId = e.target.attributes.identifier.value //Node ID retrieved
      //Handle action based off of node type
      if nodeType is "department_node" or nodeType is "department_node_label"
        scope.departmentClicked(nodeId)
      else if nodeType is "school_node" or nodeType is "school_node_label"
        scope.schoolClicked(nodeId)
      else if nodeType is "user_node" or nodeType is "user_node_label"
        scope.userClicked(nodeId)
```

By doing things this way, I now have one event handler in my directive that retrieves and identifies the data and sends instructions to my graph manager to update the graph, rather than having an event listener per node